# Looking for an anchor with Angular example

Tags: anchor

hey anyone has an example of anchor with Angular?
i want to integrate a solana program to an existing Angular app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after hours of research in GitHub and asking in Discord groups i found this two examples:

https://github.com/heavy-duty/platform

https://github.com/danmt/transaction-processor